# Need to get ID of an item selected in a MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of Accounts (entities), and each account has 0:n events. (entity_event).

```
Select 
    e.id,
    e.description, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ee.source_entity_id = e.id THEN 1 ELSE -1 END * ISNULL(ee.amount,0)) AS Total, 
    MAX(ee.event_date) AS LastTransactionDate
from entity e
left join entity_event ee
on ee.source_entity_id = e.id or ee.destination_entity_id = e.id
where e.deleted is NULL
and e.portfolio_id = 79
and e.entity_type_id = 1

GROUP BY e.id, e.description
order by e.description
```

In the above query, I am getting all the events, along with the last date a transaction was done on, as well as the total amount worth of transactions.

What I also need, is the ID of the last paid transaction.

I am getting the MAX(ee.event_date) - but is there a way to get the id of that entity_event as well? If there's more than one event on that date - then I want the last one.

Or do  need sub queries here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use window functions instead of `group by`, then you can fetch all the other columns from the record.  Here is what the query looks like:

```
select t.*
from (Select e.id, e.description, 
             SUM(CASE WHEN ee.source_entity_id = e.id THEN 1 ELSE -1 END * ISNULL(ee.amount, 0)) OVER
                 (partition by e.id) AS Total, 
             MAX(ee.event_date) over (partition by e.id) AS LastTransactionDate,
             row_number() over (partition by e.id order by ee.event_date desc) as seqnum
      from entity e left join entity_event
           ee
           on ee.source_entity_id = e.id or ee.destination_entity_id = e.id
      where e.deleted is NULL and e.portfolio_id = 79 and e.entity_type_id = 1
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
order by e.description;
```

Comment: Perfect! Now, to work out why that works! Never used Count/Sum/Max without GROUP. Need to read up on 'window functions' now. Thanks!